# Responsive Header While Aligning Child Items with Custom Padding While Using Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, header, responsive

I'm trying to make my header responsive using flexbox but I want to add custom paddings while still keeping responsiveness, ie, on smaller screens the padding should become smaller etc

Below is my code:
I want each item to have different right and left paddings and the smaller the screen gets the smaller the padding should, like the default way flex operates

```
<nav class="menu-bar">
    <a href="#" class="logo-header"><img src="" alt="logo" /></a>
      <a href="services.html" ; class="Nav-bar" id="Services">Services</a>
    <a href="#" ; class="Nav-bar" id="Tools">Tools & Resources</a>
    <a href="#" ; class="Nav-bar" id="About">About</a>
    <a href="#" class="Nav-bar" id="pop">Contact</a>
    <a href="index.html"; class="Nav-bar"><button onclick="window.location.href='index.html';" class="quote">Client Login</button></a>
  </nav>
```

```
.menu-bar {
    width: 100%;
    background: #161B21 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    box-shadow: 0rem 1.125rem 0.813rem #00000029;
    opacity: 1;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    
    display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.Nav-bar {
    font: normal normal normal 1.625rem Poppins;
    padding-top: 86px;
    padding-bottom: 65px;
    letter-spacing: 0rem;
    color: #ABAAAA;
    opacity: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.Nav-bar:nth-of-type(n+3) {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
                                    order: 2;
}

.Nav-bar:hover {
    color: #F4A950;
}
.logo-header {
    width: 382px;
height: 73px;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
          order: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make any size proportional to the viewport width, use a vw unit, like this:

```
#some-element {padding: 1.375vw;)
```

If you find that on small screens things get too small, then work out the minimum size you'd like in pixels, then combine it with your `vw` size using a `max()` expression:

```
#some-element {padding: max(5px, 1.375vw);
```

Here is a snippet to demonstrate:

```css
header, nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 2vw;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
header {
  background: pink;
  padding: max(5px,2vw);
}
.logo img {
  width: max(48px,10vw);
}
```

```html
<header>
    <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/crunchbase-production/image/upload/c_lpad,h_256,w_256,f_auto,q_auto:eco,dpr_1/lghwq8tuwibnv2qav3q3" alt="logo" /></a>
    <nav>
        <a href="services.html" ; class="Nav-bar" id="Services">Services</a>
        <a href="#" ; class="Nav-bar" id="Tools">Tools & Resources</a>
        <a href="#" ; class="Nav-bar" id="About">About</a>
        <a href="#" class="Nav-bar" id="pop">Contact</a>
        <button onclick="window.location.href='index.html';" class="quote">Client Login</button>
    </nav>
</header>
```